# True or false statements

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

> Two of the following statements are true and one is false
>
> a) For all rational numbers $q$, there exists an integer $n$ so that $q+n=271$.
> b) For all integers $n$, there exists a rational number $q$ so that $q+n=271$.
> c) There exists an integer $n$ so that $271-n$ is even.

I believe a and c are true and b is false

Comment: If I say that $q$ is $270.5$ (a rational number), can you show me an integer $n$ such that $q+n=271$?

Comment: Is there _any_ integer I can subtract from 271 to get an even number?  Try a few different small positive integers (say, under 5).

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- For any integers $x$ and $y$, their difference $x-y$ is an integer.
- Every integer is a rational number.
- $\frac{1}{2}$ is a rational number.